# Cohomology groups of the Klein bottle from the definition of cellular cohomology.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Hatcher has very minimal treatment of direct cohomology computation. For a greater depth of understanding I want to make sure that I can still compute cohomology straight from the definitions of cellular cohomology, the Mayer-vietoris sequence, etc...

I'm trying to compute the cohomology groups of the Klein bottle using cellular cohomology. We know that the Klein bottle has a CW complex consisting of one 0-cell, two 1-cells and one 2-cell. Hence we have a cochain complex given by $$0 \longleftarrow \mathbb{Z} \longleftarrow \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \longleftarrow \mathbb{Z} \longleftarrow 0.$$ My confusion is on how we compute the coboundary maps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to know what the maps are. Let $C_0,C_1$ and $C_2$ be the free groups on the cells. Then  you have

$$0\rightarrow C_2\rightarrow C_1 \rightarrow C_1\rightarrow 0$$
$$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$$

and $$\partial_2 (n)=(2n,0)$$
$$\partial_1(n,m)=0$$ so for the homology groups we get 
$$H_2,H_1,H_0$$
$$0,\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}$$

Now to get the cohomology we have to find the maps for

$$0\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(C_0, \mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(C_1, \mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(C_2, \mathbb{Z})\rightarrow 0$$
$$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$$

So $$\delta_0 f (a,b)=f(\partial_1(a,b))=0$$
thus $\delta_0=0$.
$$\delta_1 g (n)=g(\partial_2(n))=g(2n,0)$$ 
By choosing an appropriate basis for $C^1$ we can think of this map as
$(a,b)\mapsto 2a$.

Thus for cohomology we get

$$H^0,H^1,H^2$$
$$\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}_2$$

I hope this makes sense and that it helps !

Comment: Could you please explain the part "By choosing an appropriate basis for $C^1$ we can think of this map as $(a,b)\mapsto 2a$"? Thanks in advance